# Xcode code completion missing variables & methods?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I was following along with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RO8_mqRJO-4), and was very confused when I tried to access:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor
```

The reason I was confused is because Xcode doesn't show "barTintColor" as part of it's code completion.

Instead, it offers me "tintColor" and "backgroundColor", both of which do not work like the tutorial. However, when I manually type in "barTintColor" it works correctly.

Why would "barTintColor" not show up as part of my code completion? And is there something I can do to avoid similar confusion in the future?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, you're experiencing behavior because `barTintColor` is a property of a `UINavigationBar`, and not a property on the `UIApperance` protocol.  Code completion must be trying to get the possible methods on the internal `_UIAppearance.Type` (the type of `appearance()`) rather than the `UINavigationBar` class.